# C2664: while compiling in 64bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, 64-bit

Hi I have a source code working fine when compiled using vs2008, in 32 bit. Now I am trying to compile the same source code in 64bit. For this piece of code:

```
if(EnumResourceLanguages(gHResources, RT_STRING, MAKEINTRESOURCE(1),EnumLangProc, 0) && (0 < gNumSupportedLangs))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: error C2664: 'EnumResourceLanguagesA' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'BOOL (__cdecl *)(HMODULE,LPCTSTR,LPCTSTR,WORD,LONG)' to 'ENUMRESLANGPROCA'
```

Can any help me with how to get rid of it?

Comment: What is `EnumLangProc`? The error message is obviously related to `EnumLangProc`. You have to remember to post the declaration of `EnumLangProc`, if the error message refers to `EnumLangProc`.

Comment: It also looks like the last parameter should be `LONG_PTR` instead of `LONG`. Either way make sure the declaration of `EnumLangProc` matches  [`ENUMRESLANGPROC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648033\(v=vs.85\).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 4th parameter of the callback is defined as `LONG`. The `EnumResLangProc` expects `LONG_PTR` as 4th parameter. This is a bug in the code but in 32-bit `LONG` is the same size as `LONG_PTR` (4 bytes) so it compiles fine. In 64-bit `LONG_PTR` is 8 bytes long so you get an error. Change your callback signature to accept `LONG_PTR` as 4th parameter and it will compile for both 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: @vivek, You should accept this answer. Like icepack said, my observation is correct, but this answer explains the actual problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your callback is using the `__cdecl` calling convention. Instead it needs to use the `__stdcall` calling convention. The appropriate function prototype would be:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumLangProc(HMODULE, LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR, WORD, LONG_PTR);
```

`CALLBACK` is essentially `#define`d to be `__stdcall`.

Comment: BOOL CALLBACK
EnumLangProc(
 HMODULE  hModule,
 LPCTSTR  type,
 LPCTSTR  name,
 WORD  language,
 LONG  userData)

Comment: This is what I have the definition for EnumLangProc

Comment: @chris while your calling convention observation is correct, it's not the cause for this error

Comment: @icepack, I'm pretty sure it's caused me problems in the past, but yes, I forgot the error only happened in 64-bit, which makes sense with the way `LONG_PTR` is `typedef`d.

Comment: @icepack, Actually, my recollection might have been me using a signature of `DWORD()` for a thread procedure instead of `DWORD WINAPI(LPVOID)` and then changing both things later. That would fit.